# 5 most important seo

Tags: seo

would you list 5 most important seo jobs to do , that you have achieved on your personal experiences.

thanks

Comment: this is not a programming question...

Comment: Hmmm, there are lot of basic questions about SEO already in this forum http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/237/basic-seo-optimization, http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-your-sites-position-in-google. I don't know if this is is really any different.

Comment: @John: perhaps it could work as a Community Wiki, if it was cleaned up a little? Otherwise it's a poor-quality question that should be closed.

Comment: Since this was never cleaned up it is being closed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to correctly fill the title tag, use the h1 tags, have link from other websites with good Anchor texts.

Having a good domain name and the server location can also help.

Comment: +1 for title and h1. can you explain the `server location` part? (you mean geographical location, for experienced speed?)

Comment: As the speed the content is delivered influence the ranking, having a server near your market also help.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my top 3 answers in order of importance (most important first):

1. Create good content.
2. Get people talking about your site and build incoming links. Contact blogs, news sites, etc. and try and convince them to discuss your site. Make sure these sites **have related content**.
3. Ensure you have good, clean structure and property meta tags, etc. so the engines can understand your site.

Answer (score 0):

Having good content and clean semantic HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to others, some thoughts that pop into a virtual balloon, between my mind and my monitor:

- (Get to) `know your audience` well >> direct your seo links towards websites they visit
- Get `feedback from your audience` >> and reflect this on your website
- `Involve your audience` into your site
- `trigger actions` that directs your audience towards you
- never lose your `passion over any seo benefits`: put your love into your site
- the rest will `be noticed by people` automatically and they'll handle the rest for you!